# Second order ODE with exponential coefficient, $Y''(x)+aY'(x)+b^2e^{2ax}Y(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

How to find the solution of the given equation?. Can it be transformed to a Bessel equation or equation with constant coefficients?.
$$Y''(x)+aY'(x)+b^2e^{2ax}Y(x)=0$$
Thank you

Comment: Hi there, your question as currently phrased is likely to attract close votes and downvotes. To avoid this and also to get the best answers suited to your understanding, I suggest checking [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/)

Comment: I tried the substitution manually but wasn't successful. Please, can you share the substitution, if you have done it manually?

Comment: I've used $t=\exp(-ax)$ and obtained equation like $y''(t)+c^2 y(t) / t^4 = 0$

Answer (score 3):

We first assume $a\neq 0$. We start by substituting $y(x)=e^{-ax}u(x)$. Note that
$$y'(x)=e^{-ax} u'(x)-ae^{-ax}u(x),$$
$$y''(x)=e^{-ax}u''(x)-2ae^{-ax}u'(x)+a^2 e^{-ax}u(x).$$
Therefore, one obtains the ODE
$$e^{-ax}u''(x)-ae^{-ax}u'(x)+b^2 e^{ax}u(x)=0.$$
Since $e^{-ax}\neq 0$, one can divide by $e^{-ax}$ to obtain
$$u''(x)-au'(x)+b^2 e^{2ax}u(x)=0.\tag{1}$$
We now substitute $z=e^{ax}$. One finds that $z'(x)=az$, thus by the chain rule one obtains
$$u'(x)=azu'(z),$$
$$u''(x)=a^2 z^2 u''(z)+a^2 zu'(z).$$
Substituting this into $(1)$ gives you
$$a^2 z^2u''(z)+b^2 z^2 u(z)=0.$$
One can divide by $a^2 z^2=a^2 e^{2ax}\neq 0$ therefore one obtains a simple ODE with constant coefficients
$$u''(z)+\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2u(z)=0.$$
If $a=0$ the ODE is already in a similar form in $y(x)$, so you don't need to do any substitutions.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance...

Comment: @projectilemotion...Please can you comment on the given equation, whether it can be reduced to two 2nd order differential equations. If yes, how it can be done.                 X^2 * Y''''[X] + 2 * (a+2) * X * Y'''[X] + (a+2) (a+1) * Y''[X] - b^4 * Y[x] = 0

Comment: @projectilemotion...how can we compute the order of bessel function if it has dependency on indpendent variable as J(1/2+ax) in which x is independent variable and a is constant.